# Create centOS6 snapshots

Tags: centos6, snapshot

How can I create snapshots of system (similar to what VM have) of a centOS 6 to a network location? 
That is I need to know what software/package should I use and maybe some ways to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about Physical or Virtual machine ? Physical i guess...

If Physical, of course **you cannot** create snapshot similar to VMWare ! This question doesn't make much sense.

However, an alternative could be to create an image of the entire disk of the machine and store the image in a safe location, to recover the machine later.

Something like [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) will do this job. It allows you to store direclty the image on a network location.

Comment: I am talking of a physical machine. And yes I would want something similar to Virtualbox/VMWare type of snapshot of the OS and done automatically within the same machine. Is it possible?

Comment: As far as i know it is not possible. There are also other alternative like http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-clone-linux-systems http://www.rsnapshot.org or http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page But nothing that will really act like a Virtual Machine snapshot.  The term "snapshot" can be used when talking about LVM, that offers "snapshot" feature (never tested it) http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/snapshot_command.html